# How can I change the resolution in Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Whenever I first started playing Kingdoms of Amalur, I noticed the cutscenes only filled about half of my screen. It fit from bottom to top, but on the sides I had black bars similar to a letterbox format DVD. I figured it just did this to get the cutscenes a more cinematic feel; but when the cutscenes ended, the bars didn't go away!

I tried taking a screenshot, but it ignored these black bars altogether. I have a 17" Widescreen monitor and would like to get rid of these annoying bars. Seeing no option to change the resolution in the in-game menus, I'm curious:

**Is there any way to fill my screen with this gorgeous game?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably that you're trying to change the resolution while your character is loaded, instead of exiting back to the main menu and doing it from there. For some reason, once you're already playing your character, the option to change your resolution disappears.

[image]

Comment: Wow, *now* I feel like an idiot...

Comment: @Tristan I think whoever designed their options menu should feel like an idiot. I guess they just didn't want to implement a resolution switch that didn't force you to restart the game.